# How do I replace this character using PHP?

Tags: php, xml

The character comes from an XML feed.

Here is an excerpt:

```
Kock’s parole
```

As you see, it is not a normal `'`

We tried

```
$sql = str_replace("’", "\'", $sql);
```

But that does nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly is `$sql`? Raw text? Do you know what encoding it's in?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743812/how-to-use-str-replace-to-replace-single-and-double-quotes

Comment: It is the raw XML data.

Comment: what is your expected answer

Comment: @Jacques: Why is it called `$sql` if it's XML? Anyway, if it's XML then the encoding has to be already known. What is that encoding? UTF-8? What encoding is your source code saved in?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
$sql = str_replace("’", "\'", $sql);
```

with

```
$sql = str_replace("’", "'", $sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = str_replace( chr(146), "\'", $sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if this is an sql statement, you will have to do something like this:

```
$sql = str_replace("’", "\\\'", $sql);
```

So for example if you sql statement is something like this:

```
$name = "Kock’s parole";
$name = str_replace("’", "\\\'", $name);
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (`name`) VALUES ('$name')";
```

then this will work fine for you.